# Can I use nested type in Scala generic function?

Tags: scala

How can I use nested type in Scala generic function ? I'd like to implement something like this

```
implicit def basicDBList2List[List[A]](value : BasicDBList) = value.toList.asInstanceOf[List[A]]
```

Compiler gives following error:

```
scala: not found: type A
  implicit def basicDBList2List[List[A]](value : BasicDBList) = value.toList.asInstanceOf[List[A]]
                                                                                               ^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write:

```
implicit def basicDBList2List[List[A]](value: BasicDBList) = ...
```

... that doesn't mean what you think it means. You're declaring a new type parameter called `List`, not referring to the existing `List` trait in the library! You're also declaring that your newly-defined `List` type requires some type parameter, which you've called `A`, but you can't actually reference it.

What you probably meant was:

```
implicit def basicDBList2List[A](value: BasicDBList): List[A] = ...
```

... which says that, for any type `A`, you can convert a `BasicDBList` to a `List[A]`.

This is sketchy code, though, for two reasons:

1. What type does your `BasicDBList` class actually contain? Probably not any possible `A`. You'll very likely get `ClassCastException` at runtime.
2. Why do you want an implicit conversion from `BasicDBList` to `List[A]`? That's almost always a bad idea.

Comment: I have to wrap shitty mongo java driver so I don't have to pollute client code with casting. So basically when I fetch particular field from Mongo DB I know what type it is.

Comment: Shitty casbah is the reason I started playing with implicits :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better have it like:

```
implicit def basicDBList2List[A](value : BasicDBList) = value.toList.asInstanceOf[List[A]]
```